# Патерн для замены пачки if else

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, if

Подскажите, может есть какое-то более элегантное решение написания с заменой полотна из 20 ифов?

```
if (null != req.getParameter("removeExclude")) {
    String exclude_id = req.getParameter("exclude_id");
    db.removeExclude(exclude_id);
    return;
}
if (null != req.getParameter("getProdGroupDate")) {
    db.getProdGroupDate(out);
    return;
}
if (null != req.getParameter("getProdGroupByDate")) {
    db.getProdGroupByDate(out, req.getParameter("date"));
    return;
}
if (null != req.getParameter("createProdPhone")) {
    if(req.getParameter("pass").equals("androidapppass")){
        db.createProdPhone(req.getParameter("cat"), req.getParameter("code"));
    }
    return;
}
```

и так далее, и так далее....

Comment: Можно `switch case`

Comment: Шаблон проектирования нужно было внедрять раньше, чтобы не было такой портянки. Смотрите в сторону рефлексии.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать в функциональном стиле пописать, например так, но на `java` не особо то удобно получается.

```
 Predicate<String> predicate = paramName -> req.getParameter(paramName) != null;

 Map<String, Runnable> tasks = new LinkedHashMap<>();
 tasks.put("removeExclude", () -> {
        String exclude_id = req.getParameter("exclude_id");
        db.removeExclude(exclude_id);
 });
 tasks.put("getProdGroupDate", () -> db.getProdGroupDate(out));

 tasks.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> predicate.test(entry.getKey())).findFirst();
```